# Angular reinitialize component when i go back to previous component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using angular v5.

I have home component and home2 component

routing set up :

```
{
  path: "home", 
  component: homecomponent
}, 
{
  path:"home2", 
  component: home2component
}
{
  path:"**", 
  redirectTo:"/home", 
  pathMatch: "full"
}
```

I am facing issue when redirect back to home component. home component complete reinitialise.

How to manage home component's state?

Comment: You don't want to reinitialize the component?

Comment: yes. i don't want to reinitialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing state is a hard problem. We need to coordinate multiple backends, web workers, and UI components, all of which update the state concurrently.

You can use **Ngrx** to manage State of a component in Angular 2+

**This is the interaction between those components in NgRx:**

[image: This is the interaction between those components in NgRx]

There are five parts that constitute NgRx:

1. Store
2. List item
3. Reducers (and Meta-Reducers)
4. Actions
5. Selectors
6. Effects

The Ngrx provides a single source of truth for the state of your application.

You can understand more about Ngrx [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-ngrx-for-state-management-in-an-ionic-angular-application/)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but my application very complex. i can't add state management in my application

Answer (score 1):

That is normal behavior because when you visit your angular component Angular will trigger life cycle hook `ngOnInit` to init the component

After you navigate away from your component component will get destroy using `ngOnDestroy` to avoid memory leak.

Comment: ok got it. but how to manage it without using state management library.

Comment: do you have you idea. how to prevent to destroy?